# tzinfo conflict with mongoid and rufus-scheduler

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, rufus-scheduler, tzinfo

I try to use mongoid 3.x together with rufus-scheduler 2.x and im always getting a gem conflict over tzinfo.

```
Unable to activate mongoid-3.1.4, because tzinfo-1.0.1 conflicts with tzinfo (~> 0.3.22)
```

Looks like mongoid has some dependency on some legacy tzinfo version.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Gemfile, specify the version of TzInfo that suits Mongoid, before Mongoid and before rufus-scheduler (rufus-scheduler accepts any version of TzInfo).

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'tzinfo', '0.3.22'
gem 'mongoid', '3.1.4'
gem 'rufus-scheduler'
```

**UPDATE**

Updated rufus-scheduler 2.0.x so that it accepts >= 0.3.22 (https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/commit/18c98010)

Unfortunately, can't seem to be able to push to RubyGems.org for now (it goes 500).

Until I find a workaround, you can point to that new rufus-scheduler with

```
gem 'rufus-scheduler', :git => 'git://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler.git', :branch => 'two'
```

**UPDATE**

Could push rufus-scheduler 2.0.24 to rubygems https://rubygems.org/gems/rufus-scheduler

It should be OK now.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately rufus-scheduler has the dependency tzinfo >= 0.3.23 (https://rubygems.org/gems/rufus-scheduler) while mongoid has the version fixed on 0.3.22 (http://rubygems.org/gems/mongoid)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was looking at rufus-scheduler master which has no version constraint for its tzinfo dependency. Let me cook something...